# iOS can only play 4 videos before it stalls

Tags: ios, html, iframe, youtube-api

I'd like to know if anyone has found a solution to the problem in the link above:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube-api-gdata/EDqVaT5AMYk

> For the first video, the user needs to click the iframe's "play"
>   button.  But after that subsequent videos can be loaded and played
>   using loadVideoById.  However, after playing 4 or 5 videos, the player
>   stalls in the "buffering" state (state 3).  The only way I can set to
>   restart the video at that point is to click on the video area which
>   will cause the play button to appear.

The answer (10/11/2011):

> "This is an iOS bug which I think can be improved by not creating new
>   video tags on every playback...
>
> "We have a limit right now arbitrarily set to 4. Until we figure out
>   the right way to hold onto good video tags, we'll have this problem no
>   matter what...this will probably take a while to get resolved."